# Why class field will be shared by child classes?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

### My stupid, I just find that it is static variable in python.

I find a strange thing in python, if the class field is init not in `__init__` will be something like `static`(shared by all child classes):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class P:
    mem = list()

    def test(self):
        pass


class C1(P):
    def test(self):
        self.mem.append(1)


class C2(P):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c1 = C1()
    c2 = C2()

    c1.test()
    print(c2.mem) # output [1]
```

I find it will output `[1]` at last, because it is changed by `c1`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class P:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mem = list()

    def test(self):
        pass


class C1(P):
    def test(self):
        self.mem.append(1)


class C2(P):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c1 = C1()
    c2 = C2()

    c1.test()
    print(c2.mem) # output []
```

Then I change it to `__init__` function, it will not be shared by all child classes.

I just want to know the reason why it will be shared by child classes in the first code?

Comment: "I find a strange thing in python, if the class field is init not in `__init__` will be something like static" - yes, that is the syntax for a static variable in Python.

Comment: Variables in outside methods are created once when the class is defined. If you assign it in `__init__()` it gets created newly for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is the difference between class attributes and instance attributes.
When you define an attribute in the class itself, like in your first example, it is shared by all instances of that class and any of its subclasses.
This means that if you modify it in any instance, it will be modified in all other instances as well.

If you instead create an instance attribute, like you did in your second example, then it is unique to that instance and not shared with the other ones.